# Sentiment Analysis using RNN through Stanford Core NLP

Tags: deep-learning, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to perform **sentiment analysis on twitter data** using standard Machine Learning algorithms ( SVM , Logistic Regresression , Naive Bayes etc) . Now i want to compare these results from **Deep Learning** algorithms . So first off i wanted to know if Stanford Core NLP Package provides libraries for deep learning 
**(RNN specifically)** .

Stanford has already written a paper on **Recursive Deep Models** and implemented it as well . https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/
But they use an already trained model , which was trained using Sentiment Tree Bank .

Is there a way to plugin my own twitter dataset and train this model and perform classification ?

Comment: You might want to have a look at spacy, which now implements stanford: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanfordnlp